# Specified cast is not valid by sharepoint.linq.dll

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, linq-to-sql

I am writing code to check if an item exist in a sharepoint document library, I have generated entity classes using sp metal. The code is below:

```
public bool? checkRSA(string pin)
    {
        bool ?checkIfRsaExists = null;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
        {
            string siteURL = "http://dms.site.com/sites/DirOperations/CustomerCare";
            CustomercareDataContext CustCareDB = new CustomercareDataContext(siteURL);
            checkIfRsaExists = CustCareDB.GetList<BenefitsCT>("RSAs Library").ScopeToFolder("", true).Any(x => x.RSAPIN == pin);
        });
        return checkIfRsaExists;
    }
```

Now each time I run this code it throws an error: Specified cast is not valid.

The stack trace is below:

> StackTrace    at Set__permi(Object , Object )\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPItemMappingInfo.MaterializeEntity[TEntity](DataContext
>   dc, SPDataList list, SPListItem item, SPItemMappingInfo
>   itemMappingInfo, JoinPath joinPath)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   SPListItem )\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n 
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPLinqProvider.Execute[T](Expression
>   expression)\r\n   at
>   linkApprovals.WebService1.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0() in
>   c:\users\sp_admin\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\linkApprovals\linkApprovals\WebService1.asmx.cs:line
>   75\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)"  string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. It turns out the context file generated by SP Metal is corrupt. The stack trace pointed out the solution. I removed the __permi(Object , Object ) and it worked perfectly.